# Remove dotted lines in Microsoft word for mac

Tags: microsoft-word

Do you see those dots in the image here:

[image]

I can't remove them.  The dots refer to where a page break hypothetically would appear if I were to print it.  But I don't care about that for now.  It's too distracting.

I have Microsoft Word for Mac, roughly year 2021.  In format > paragraph > line and page breaks, none of the options available remove the dotted line. In Word for PC it seems there is an option under home > paragraph > borders > no border, but that option is not found in Word for Mac.  Here are the settings that I think are most relevant:

[image]

[image]

Here is the link to the file

https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0dfatl2TIS1UKkhn7nD3JIfnA#dotted_lines

Comment: If it really is a paragraph border, try the main menu (at the top of the screen, then Format->Borders and Shading, click the Borders tab, then under "Setting:" click None.

Comment: Can you show us more of your screen? Would be interesting to see where the line starts and where it ends relative to the margins and the vertical position on the page.

Comment: Does this dotted line print or show up in pdf? Please save a sample document with the problem in OneDrive or DropBox and add a view link to your question.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon, thanks for your help.  The url has been provided in the updated post.

Comment: @jonsson, yea, i'm pretty sure i have those options selected.  see update.

Comment: @Loeli, done, done, done

Comment: Have tried to double-click on the line? It looks like MS Word is hidding whitespaces.

Comment: no i can't double-click on the dotted line.  can you?  i uploaded the file to icloud.  are you using word for mac?

Comment: @logic1976 No open it on Windows, and it was fine no dotted lines. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgXu0.png). But when double-clicking, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMqn.png).

Comment: @logic1976 Pretty sure that this is because you are using Draft View and these lines are just how page breaks and perhaps other break types are displayed in that view.

Comment: I also opened in Windows and did not see the line except when in print view with white space hidden. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/WhiteSpace.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated screenshot with the full screen was helpful. You are using Word in the "Draft View". In this view, Word shows a dotted line to tell you when there is a page break.
From here on it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to edit your document without seeing the page borders and without seeing what it would look like when printed, you can simply activate the "Web Layout" withing the "View" tab.

If you want to see the page borders, then you will have to activate the "Print Layout". Note, that in the print layout, the page break will be clearly visible and a gap is shown between the pages.

[image]

When you double-click on that gap then you will have a continuous page view, but the page break will be shown with a solid line:

[image]

Comment: In Windows, the page break with white space hidden shows as a dotted line like the one in the screenshots when in Print View.

Comment: thanks Loeli, that did it.  I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon didn’t know that this is different for some users. I actually do use Windows but have this solid line. In any case, it seems that there will be some sort of line which is not removable. So, in the end I guess OP will  either have to use Web Layout or accept the existence of that line. Unless someone know how to modify this behavior

Comment: @logic1976 my pleasure